# three20: ModelView over ModalView?

Tags: ios, three20

I have LunchView of Three20 in my app.
the loginScreen is now a modelview on this and only disables when the login is correct.

Now I have a about-screen, there is a button on the login screen for this.

But how to work a modelview over a modalview?

Answer (score 0):

When you make the about screen button in your login screen, make it as an IBOutlet and be sure to connect it to the method that calls your about view.  Then you can display your about screen on top of your view stack [loginscreen.view addSubview:aboutscreenView] and when you are finished, remove the aboutscreenView from the stack.  When the user logs in then you can remove the modal view.